# Compare two columns in two DataFrame and create a boolean column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to pandas. I want to compare two dataframes grouped by 2 columns of each DataFrame. In the `df1` we have `Brand` and `Signal_range` as columns. In `df2`, we have `order`, `Brand` and `signal` as columns. I need to compare 2 `Brand` and `signal` of df2 to `Sinal_range` in df1.

`df1`

```
+-------+-------------------+
|Brand  | Signal_range 
+-------+-------------------+
| AB    | {"Weak": {"low": 15, "high": 120}, "Strong": {"low": null, "high": -240}, "Average": {"low": -240, "high": 15}}
| CA    |  
| FZ    | {"Weak": {"low": 10, "high": 100}, "Strong": {"low": null, "high": -200}, "Average": {"low": -200, "high": 10}}
+-------+-------+------------+
```

`df2`

```
+-------+-------+--------+
|order  | Brand | signal | 
+-------+-------+--------+
| 1233  | AB    |  -250  |
| 34565 | AB    |   100  |
| 34552 | FZ    |   5    |
+-------+-------+--------+
```

I need to take the `signal` of a brand in `df2` and compare it to `df1`'s `Signal_range` of the brand. If the signal falls under the range of `Signal_range` then create a new column in df1 as boolean value as below

```
+-------+-------+--------------------+-------------+------------+
|order  | Brand | signal |  weak_ind | Average_ind | Strong_ind |
+-------+-------+--------------------+-------------+------------+
| 1233  | AB    |  -250  |  0        |    0        |   1        |
| 34565 | AB    |   100  |  1        |    0        |   0        |
| 34552 | FZ    |   5    |  0        |    1        |   0        |
+-------+-------+--------+-----------+-------------+------------+
```

Is there any way we can achieve this easily?

Answer (score 0):

It's all about prep.  Turn embedded JSON into columns then it's straight logic.  You have not defined your logic so I've taken stab at it for purpose of this example.

```
sr = """
|Brand|Signal_range
| AB    | {"Weak": {"low": 15, "high": 120}, "Strong": {"low": null, "high": -240}, "Average": {"low": -240, "high": 15}}
| CA    |  
| FZ    | {"Weak": {"low": 10, "high": 100}, "Strong": {"low": null, "high": -200}, "Average": {"low": -200, "high": 10}}"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(sr), sep="|", engine="python").drop(columns="Unnamed: 0")
# cleanup the data and convert JSON to columns
df["Brand"] = df["Brand"].str.strip()
df["Signal_range"] = df["Signal_range"].str.strip().replace("", "{}")
df["Signal_range"] = df["Signal_range"].apply(lambda x: json.loads(x))
df = pd.json_normalize(df.to_dict(orient="records"))
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""|order|Brand|signal
| 1233  | AB    |  -250  
| 34565 | AB    |   100  
| 34552 | FZ    |   5    """), sep="|").drop(columns="Unnamed: 0")
df1["Brand"] = df1["Brand"].str.strip()
dfm = df1.merge(df, on="Brand")
# derive columns...
dfm = dfm.assign(
    weak_ind=np.where(1, (dfm["Signal_range.Weak.low"]<=dfm["signal"])&(dfm["signal"]<=dfm["Signal_range.Weak.high"]), 0),
    average_ind=np.where(1, (dfm["Signal_range.Average.low"]<=dfm["signal"])&(dfm["signal"]<=dfm["Signal_range.Average.high"]), 0),
    strong_ind=np.where(1, (dfm["Signal_range.Strong.low"]<=dfm["signal"])&(dfm["signal"]<=dfm["Signal_range.Strong.high"]), 0),

          )
dfr = dfm.copy()
print(dfr.drop(columns=[c for c in dfr.columns if "Signal" in c]).to_string(index=False))
```

### output

```
 order Brand  signal  weak_ind  average_ind  strong_ind
  1233    AB    -250         0            0           0
 34565    AB     100         1            0           0
 34552    FZ       5         0            1           0
```

Comment: Hi @Rob Raymod  Thanks I got your idea, However I am getting TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'NoneType' while dfm.assign(). Is there any specific reason for that?

Comment: it's your data types `dfm.dtypes` returns `float64` or `int64` for all the **signal** columns in data I generated from your sample data.  clearly <= is a number comparison.  type using `astype()` to cast your actual data to number types